# Arc length of $y = 50 - 1/10(x-15)^2$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, arc-length

I'm not quite sure how to proceed with this problem.

> The wind is blowing a kite towards the west. The altitude of the kite is
>   $$y = 50 - (1/10)(x-15)^2$$
>   and it is being displaced horizontally from 25 meters to 0 meters. What is the length of the string?

Comment: If you draw a picture, you'll have a right-angled triangle.